# how to store array content in an hash with hash_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
# Get a Nokogiri::HTML::Document for the page we’re interested in...
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("data.xml"))
# Search for nodes by css

ids = []
@doc.xpath('//itemid').each do |link|
    ids << link.content
end

hash = {}
i = 0
@doc.xpath('//realestate').each do |link|
    hash.store(link.to_s)
    i+=1
    #p hash
    #sleep 2
    #break if i ==1
end

 p hash
```

Everything is working fine.,except hash.store., want i want is "store the data inside the hash with hash_id.. thanks

Comment: Normally people will use hash to store key/value pair. In your case you are storing the value link.to_s only. What is the need of hash?

Comment: i try with the ruby code **hash.store(id,link.to_s)** but it showing the error.

Comment: `hash.store(key, value)` is the same as `hash[key]=(value)`. Just use `[]` instead of `#store`. The error should be you not providing both key and value args.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you don't want a hash: you're not trying to associate one piece of data with another. Instead, perhaps you are looking for a Set. Try:

```
require 'set'

s = Set.new

# Later
s << link.to_s
```

Or more simply:

```
require 'set'
links = Set.new( @doc.xpath('//realestate').map(&:to_s) )
```

Comment: +1 For this use the Set is the way to go. It will maintain uniqueness, though the OP probably should force the URL to lower-case or upper-case and trim session IDs and normalize the query parameters' order and... and... and.... In short it opens a whole new can of worms. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data structure is but this can help:

```
> array = [[1, 'value1'], [2,'value2']]
=> [[1, "value1"], [2, "value2"], [2, "othervalue"]]
> hash = array.group_by { |e| e[0] }
=> {1=>[[1, "value1"]], 2=>[[2, "value2"], [2, "othervalue"]]}
```

Comment: actually this is output i need while printing the hash... please send the ruby code to store in hash... i tryied with hash.store(id.link.to_s)